# Nest js: class created by injection is shared across 2 services

Tags: dependency-injection, module, nestjs

In Nest Js, I have a module definition:

```
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(), HelperModule],
  providers: [
    NEtheriumChainService,
    NBinanceChainService,
    NBitcoinChainService,
    NChainServiceProvider,
    {
      provide: Web3,
      useValue: new Web3(),
    },
  ],
  exports: [NChainServiceProvider],
})
export class NChainsModule {}
```

NEtheriumChainService and NBinanceChainService both accept a Web3 class in their constructor. I would have thought that this syntax would provide each service with its own Web3 instance, but they end up with the same instance of Web3 - effectively sharing it. How do I ensure that each service has its own dedicated Web3 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the release of nest.js 6.0, [injection scopes](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#scopes) were added. With this, you can choose one of the following three scopes for your providers:

- **SINGLETON**: Default behavior. One instance of your provider is used for the whole application
- **TRANSIENT**: A dedicated instance of your provider is created for every provider that injects it.
- **REQUEST**: For each request, a new provider is created. Caution: This behavior will bubble up in your dependency chain. Example: If UsersController (Singleton) injects UsersService (Singleton) that injects OtherService (Request), then both UsersController and UsersService will automatically become request-scoped.

What you need is **TRANSIENT**

#### Usage

Either add it to the `@Injectable()` decorator:

```js
    @Injectable({ scope: Scope.TRANSIENT })
    export class Web3 {}
```

Or set it for custom providers in your module definition:

```js
    {
      provide: "Web3",
      useClass: Web3,
      scope: Scope.TRANSIENT,
    }
```

Comment: Weird, I made the change and fully expected it to work, but the 2 services were still sharing the same Web3 instance. There may be something more involved. For now I had to override what was passed to the constructors and create a new instance of Web3 in each service directly.

Comment: I edited the answer try the second snippet again.